# Trying to understand naming rules in AngularJS services

Tags: angularjs

In John Papas coding guidelines for AngularJS he says that the "type" of declaration does not need to be in the name only if that type is controller because controllers are frequently used.  I'm confused on his logger service why it is not required to be loggerService.

https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#services

```
// service
angular
 .module('app')
 .service('logger', logger);

function logger() {
  this.logError = function(msg) {
    /* */
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his post he says the type (controller, service...) is optional.

> Use consistent names for all components following a pattern that
>   describes the component's feature then (optionally) its type. My
>   recommended pattern is feature.type.js. There are 2 names for most
>   assets:

I assume that something like "logger" is very explicit so he doesn't need the "service" type on it.

Comment: I'm only looking at his coding guidelines.  He says:  "Note: Another common convention is naming controller files without the word controller in the file name such as avengers.js instead of avengers.controller.js. All other conventions still hold using a suffix of the type. Controllers are the most common type of component so this just saves typing and is still easily identifiable. I recommend you choose 1 convention and be consistent for your team."

Comment: Sorry... I said post but I meant that same doc you are referring to. Here's the naming convention part of the guidelines.  https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide#naming

Comment: Thanks.  I must be going blind because I can't find the mention of service (just controller as the exception). It's OK, I believe you and don't need to clobber this issue more.